# so how to add a column on table with calculating

Tags: sql

I made a query and with the result below:

```
select claim_by, count(*) as total_response, 
       count (response_time > minute (response_time -30)) as total_target,
       count(response_time > minute (response_time +30)) as total_untarget,
       (COUNT(claim_by)/alltotal) * 100 AS percentage_total_response
from itcorp_first_response,
     (SELECT COUNT(claim_by) AS alltotal 
      FROM itcorp_first_response) AS alltotal
GROUP BY claim_by;
```

[image]

so how to add a column with calculating total_target/total_response * 100 in query..?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try subquery

```
select *,(total_target/total_response) as [total_target/total_response] from
(
select 
claim_by, 
count(*) as total_response, 
       count (response_time > minute (response_time -30)) as total_target,
       count(response_time > minute (response_time +30)) as total_untarget,
       (COUNT(claim_by)/alltotal) * 100 AS percentage_total_response
from itcorp_first_response,
     (SELECT COUNT(claim_by) AS alltotal 
      FROM itcorp_first_response) AS alltotal
GROUP BY claim_by
)XX
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help but I can't make a view table and get below error :

SQL Error [1349] [HY000]: (conn=45714) View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Comment: solved with this query;

count(claim_by)/(SELECT COUNT(claim_by) FROM itcorp_first_response) * 100 AS percentage_total_response

solved, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write it out:

```
select claim_by, count(*) as total_response, 
       count (response_time > minute (response_time -30)) as total_target,
       count(response_time > minute (response_time +30)) as total_untarget,
       (COUNT(claim_by)/alltotal) * 100 AS percentage_total_response,
       count (response_time > minute (response_time -30)) / count(*) *100
from itcorp_first_response,
     (SELECT COUNT(claim_by) AS alltotal 
      FROM itcorp_first_response) AS alltotal
GROUP BY claim_by;
```